# pfx file not found for Xero api

Tags: asp.net

I'm developing an app that accesses the Xero api and what I have works fine on my development machine.

When I upload to my web server (arvixe) I get a file not found error when trying to load the pfx file required for authentication.

I have verified the file path is correct and enabled permissions on the file.

Could this error be masking something else?

** UPDATE **

There is no problem accessing the file.  I changed the code to load the pfx file into a byte array first which works fine, then use the byte array as a parameter to the x509certificate2 constructor instead of the filename.

This is where the error occurs, so it looks like it has a problem creating a temporary file or accessing the certificate store.

I think this might be a problem on shared hosting.  Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this randomly started working today.  I had tried this code before, but after many other things, it's possible I just needed to recycle the application pool:

```
  X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
  cert.Import(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/public_privatekey.pfx"), "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

The key part is the storage flag of MachineKeySet.